# Fallback or Disable Angularjs HTML5 pushstate in IE9

Tags: angularjs, node.js, html, pushstate

I know this question is already raised but i haven't came across something i'm looking for. Pushstate works in  modern browser and i have also created corresponding routes in Nodejs to make Deeplink url work.

In IE9 everything works based on  `hashtag`, what i would like to do is disable the hash navigation and make page reload. Below is a sample 
Please share your suggestions.

My app is behind SSO using saml which strips hash url during redirect. So i would prefer to  go with page refresh for IE9 and below without making much changes in angular.

```
var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

http://runnable.com/VQyIqp-EgBls-foR/nodejs-angularjs-history-for-express-and-node-js

-- UPDATE--

Now i have enabled route only for browsers which supports push state. For IE9 it will be normal page reload and routing is broken now.  I'm trying to figure out trigger a controller dynamically.

`-- Update on 03/25/2015 --`

I have created a hack for IE9 and used `nginclude` instead of `ngview`. Demo is updated with the code you can try it in IE9 and other modern browsers.

`-- Update on 03/30/2015 --`

Runnable demo was not saved and published before, now its upadated and works in IE9 also.